# Querying two tables for a condition (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a two tables `A` and `B` which have similar `cust_id` column. I am trying to retrieve all the rows where the `cust_id` are equal for `A` and `B` but have different email addresses.

What I have now is the following:

```
SELECT
    A.cust_id,
    A.email_addr,
    B.preferred_email
FROM
    email_feature A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN email_feature_sum B ON
        (
            A.cust_id = B.cust_id
            AND
            A.email_addr != B.preferred_email
        )
ORDER BY
    A.date_loaded DESC
```

but it isn't returning any results and I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from each table that you would expect to be returned by the query?  This looks like it should do what you're trying to do.  Perhaps the tables have the email strings in different localization or they need to be trimmed due to leading spaces, etc?

Comment: @user681574 Yes you're right. The cust_id has a leading zero in table A but table B doesn't have the leading zero therefore I do have to trim.

Comment: Just double checking here - does that fix your issue, or did you want some help forming the join including the trim?

Comment: @user681574 Hi, I never used trim before and not sure how to remove the first leading zero. The leading zero only occurs in table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comment on the OP above, I believe the A.cust_id needs to have leading zeroes trimmed.  This can be accomplished as follows:

If the B.cust_id is in a numeric format, you may also have to cast it as a string for the comparison to work.  I have included this in the join, but if it is not needed because B.cust_id is already a char type, you can remove the casting and it will be more efficient.

```
SELECT
    A.cust_id,
    A.email_addr,
    B.preferred_email
FROM
    email_feature A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN email_feature_sum B ON
        (
            ltrim(A.cust_id, '0') = to_char(B.cust_id)
            AND
            A.email_addr != B.preferred_email
        )
ORDER BY
    A.date_loaded DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the ordering of the result set is throwing you off.  What if you do a regular `join`?

```
SELECT ef.cust_id, ef.email_addr, efs.preferred_email
FROM email_feature ef JOIN
     email_feature_sum efs ON 
     ON ef.cust_id = efs.cust_id and
        ef.email_addr <> efs.preferred_email
ORDER BY ef.date_loaded desc;
```

Comment: Hmm I used both our SQL and replaced the condition to both email address are equal instead of not equal and it still didn't give me any results but I know for a fact there are a lot of data that has the same email address and cust_id so there must be something wrong in my SQL.

Comment: In that case, the `cust_id` fields don't match (in all likelihood) -- even if they look like they do.

Comment: Yes you're right. The cust_id has a leading zero in table A but table B doesn't have the leading zero therefore I do have to trim. Will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is not match the condition. I has been test and it run success.

```
with email_feature as(
select 1 cust_id,'hvv@gmail.com' email_addr from dual
),
email_feature_sum as(
    select 1 cust_id,'hvv@gmail2.com' preferred_email from dual
)

SELECT
    A.cust_id,
    A.email_addr,
    B.preferred_email
FROM
    email_feature A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN email_feature_sum B ON
        (
            A.cust_id = B.cust_id
            AND
            A.email_addr != B.preferred_email
        )
```